# How to switch off the NetLogo localization and set GUI in English?

Tags: user-interface, localization, netlogo, non-english

I just downloaded and installed the most recent version (6.1.1) of NetLogo, but I found that the GUI is not in English and the localized language is a mess when I launch it. I would like to switch off the localization and simply use the GUI in English, but I didn't find out how to do it. It will be greatly appreciated if anyone could help in this regard, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to navigate to the the Preferences dialog, the top option sets the language NetLogo will use, regardless of the system language.  This is accessible at NetLogo > Preferences... in macOS (below About, 2nd option down) or Tools > Preferences... in Windows/Linux (should be the top option above Extensions).  It's a dropdown and you can select English, hit OK, restart, and you should see the NetLogo interface in English.

Also you might want to report the localization that is a mess to [the NetLogo GitHub issues](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues) or to bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu.